# Why is for loop so slow in Racket code

Tags: loops, for-loop, scheme, racket

I am trying to find smallest non-divisor of numbers (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/105412/find-the-smallest-number-that-doesnt-divide-n). Following version using 'named let' works properly:

```
(define (f1 m)
  (let loop ((n 2))
    (cond
      [(= 0 (modulo m n))
       (loop (+ 1 n))]
      [else n])))
```

I am testing with:

```
(f 24)
(f 1234567)
(f 12252240)
(f 232792560)
```

Above version produces prompt output of: 5 2 19 and 23.

However, following version which uses built-in `for` loop is very slow and actually crashes with out of memory error with larger numbers:

```
(define (f2 m)
  (for/first ((i (range 2 m))
              #:when (not (= 0 (modulo m i)))
              #:final (not (= 0 (modulo m i))))
    i))
```

Is there some error in the code of second version or is `for` loop inefficient as compared with named let in Racket?

Comment: Try replacing `range` with `in-range`.

Comment: I did not expect so much difference between range and in-range. What are the advantages of range function (apart from a shorter name)? Why is the range function there at all?

Comment: Because sometimes you want a list, not a sequence. `range` produces a list, `in-range` produces a sequence (and additionally cooperates with `for` to improve iteration performance). Perhaps `range` could be adjusted to cooperate with `for` as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `range` function actually allocates a list, so the time for your function is dominated by the huge list allocation. Use `in-range` instead:

```
(define (f2 m)
  (for/first ([i (in-range 2 m)]
              #:when (not (= 0 (modulo m i)))
              #:final (not (= 0 (modulo m i))))
    i))
```

See also the section on [`for` performance](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html#%28part._for-performance%29) in the Racket Guide for more notes on the relative speed of different sequence forms.

Comment: The difference is huge!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, recursion is generally more well suited for Racket than loops. I'd approach the problem this way...

```
(define start-counter 1)

(define (f number counter)
   (cond [(not (= (modulo number counter) 0)) counter]
         [else (f number (add1 counter))]))

(define (f2 number)
   (f number start-counter))
```

Comment: You can simply define your main function as: (define (f number (counter 1))... ; This gives counter a default value of 1 and with this you do not need first and third define statement/fn. However, the reason the 'for' loop in my question is slow is clearly due to use of 'range' rather than 'in-range' function.